# Minted and floatrow incompatible

Tags: minted, floatrow

I encountered this error message while trying to use the `minted` package along the `floatrow` package:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty
Package: floatrow 2008/08/02 v0.3b floatrow: float package extension
! Package floatrow Error: Do not use float package with floatrow.
(floatrow) The latter will be skipped.
See the floatrow package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.33 \@namedef{opt@floatrow.sty}{}\endinput}
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

And I'm not Hercule Poirot at all.
I have to discard `floatrow` to make `minted` works.

mwe:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither are we: as far as I know, Hercule Poirot doesn't subscribe to the site. So a minimal example is needed.

Comment: Although the error does tell you what you've done wrong, so should be fairly intelligible even if you're not Hercule Poirot. It also tells you where to look for more information about the error.

Comment: @egreg Actually there might be a Mr. Poirot on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36554/poirot

Comment: @samcarter Might not be Hercule, though. Could be Fred Poirot.

Comment: Is `\errmessage` part of Latex? And it asks you to pretend to be Hercul Poirot? Now that is funny. How does `\ errmessage` work?

Comment: Try changing the loading order, i.e, move `\usepackage{floatrow}` before `\usepackage{minted}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The packages `float` and `floatrow` are incompatible with each other.

However, `minted` has `\RequirePackage{float}` at the beginning, so that's the source of the message. Loading the two packages in the reverse order appears to solve the issue, but it can lead to problems later.

Actually, the `float` package seems to be used just in order to provide `minted` floats with the `[H]` option, which is bad anyway. The other features of `float` relevant for `minted` can be obtained with `newfloat`, that's not incompatible with `floatrow`.

You should make a feature request to the maintainer of `minted`, so as to provide a way to disable the loading of `float`.

In the meantime, you can disable it yourself.

```
\documentclass{report}

% pretend to already have loaded float
\makeatletter 
\@namedef{ver@float.sty}{3000/12/31}
\makeatother

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

Hi

\begin{figure}
\fcapside
  {\caption{...}\label{...}}
  {...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clear explanation. And it works. By the way, can you enlight me a little more by explaning why [H] is not a good idea for figure positioning e.g. ?

Comment: @s.k There are several posts on the site about this. If you don't want something to float, then it's not a float (and should not have a caption).

Comment: Starting with `minted` v2.5 (just released), `float` is no longer loaded if the `newfloat` option is specified, and the default `listing` placement is the same as that for `figure` and `table`. So pretending to load `float` shouldn't be necessary in the future.

Comment: Note that `fr-fancy` is still incompatible with `minted`s `newfloat`.